# Does need Broadcast receiver to WakeLock

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have two questions.

1. I want fire a Broadcast receiver using AlarmManager and show a notification in onReceive method. Should I use from WakeLoke for this?
2. What is different between `setAlarmClock()` and `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` ?

Answer (score 0):

1. I use (as you wrote) the `onReceive` method to start a `newWakeLock` and it works fine for me.
2. The difference lies in the behavior in doze mode (Doze Mode: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby).

I do not know your exact problem, but I worked very hard to develop an app which contains few timers and every timer should make a notification at the exact time even the screen is locked and the device is in the doze mode. My solution is to fire an Broadcast over an AlarmManager with the `setExact(...)` method.

Comment: Alarms not fire after 48 hours in Huawei android lollipop

Comment: Do you have special  battery settings on the device (battery saver)? (I don't know if this is available on lollipop).

Comment: I don't know how to send the user to the battery settings page in android lollipop

Answer (score 0):

Answer your question in reverse order

.2. `setExactWhileIdle` guarantees that if the system is not sleeping and not in doze, the alarm will go off within 1 minute of the given time. if the system is in doze mode, the alarm will go off within 15 minutes of the given time. In practice, if the system is not in doze mode or low on battery, the alarm will go off on time. On the other hand, `setAlarmClock` is the closest one can get to a guarentee that the system will deliver the alarm at a **specific** time; this does come at a relatively large drain on battery. So, if your goal is to implement highly time sensitive notifications such as an *alarm clock*, then use `setAlarmClock`. Otherwise try to avoid it.

.1. according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)), upon an alarm being dispatched from `setExactAndAllowWhildIdle` or `setAlarmClock`:

> the app will also be added to the system's temporary power exemption list for approximately 10 seconds to allow that application to acquire further wake locks in which to complete its work.

My suggestion is that if all you are doing is posting a notification, then a wake lock is not necessary. Otherwise, if you are doing longer running work, use a wake lock

**Obligatory Disclaimer**: battery drain is a real thing. please don't make an app that drains the battery. do everything in your power to design your app not to disturb the systems power optimization. All exact alarms and especially `setAlarmClock` disrupt the systems attempts to optimize battery. If its necessary, then its necessary. Otherwise, *do not do it*.

Comment: my app should show the notification at a specific time, retrieve the next notification day and hour from the database, schedule milliseconds, and set the next alarm, Should I use WakeLock?